# How to version control common libraries?

Tags: version-control, team-foundation-server

For example, I have multiple projects which shares some common libraries:

- ProjectA

  - CommonLib1
  - CommonLib2
- ProjectB

  - CommonLib1
  - CommonLib2

At the moment, they are all in one big repository:

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- CommonLib1
- CommonLib2

However, I think it is better to have one repository for `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. But how should I manage my common libraries? A common Repository?

The Problem I have with a common repository is: It is out of sync with the specific project repository.

E.g: I want to rollback `ProjectA`. Doesn't compile. Now I need to rollback `CommonLib2`. Check in. `ProjectB` doesn't compile anymore, since it uses methods, which `CommonLib2` has not anymore.

My main problem is: How can I keep the Specific Project and the Common Project in Sync?

At the moment I use TFS VC. If there is no good answer for it, would it be for another VCS (e.g. git)?

Comment: While my possible duplicate talks about Git, the problem is the same. You have two projects with common dependencies that need to evolve at different rates. This is not a source control problem. It's a dependency management problem. Since you are in the .NET stack [NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/) is the go-to solution.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my confusion. It seems to be more overhead then simple having a project reference in the solution, but seems to be way more robust. thx @GregBurghardt

Comment: Moving those libraries into separate projects and referencing them via NuGet *is* more complicated. This additional complexity is justified when these common dependencies must evolve at different rates for different projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach is to treat CommonLib* as external dependencies - generate their deployables, store them in a separate repository, and copy them as needed into the deployables of Project*. That way, when (not if) ProjectA starts depending on a different versions than ProjectB you can easily link each of them to the specific versions of CommonLib* they support.

Comment: I am coming from a .net background. Does this mean, I need to copy a binary to the specific project and do a check in? How do I edit them?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt In the .net world you'd use nuget. Create a nuget package as part of the build process with the appropriate meta data around version numbers dependencies etc. You can then store this in a repository. This could be a nuget server (there are numerous open source and commercial nuget repositories) or just a simple file share. Once you have this then you can reference the binaries from visual studio as you would any other nuget dependency